# IIS, 206 Error, randomly started happening with one file?

Tags: iis, coldfusion, iis-6

All of a sudden I'm getting a IIS 206 Error, partial content for one javascript file. The browser is consistently only able to download 146 of 298 KB of data on multiple browsers.

I restarted the server
Tried in multiple browsers after clearing the cache and cookis
Confirmed I had permissions on the server to access the file

Still it keeps happening, the browser is unable to finish downloading the javascript file.

Any IIS guru have any ideas?

Comment: D you have CF processing JS files for some reason?

Comment: I'm not even sure how that would be possible? It finally stopped happening but for some reason was broken for 10 mins.